# How can I decode Redshift error for position and sql state?

Tags: amazon-redshift

What does each of the Redshift error messages mean?

Position: 241; [SQL State=42601, DB Errorcode=500310]

for ex, what is position 241?

What does SQL state mean and how we can find references for these?

Comment: it is a systax error that must also be in the error message something like Invalid operation: syntax error at end of input look alos at https://www.google.de/search?source=hp&ei=xFjZXqigG8SRsAfE9LHQDg&q=%5BSQL+State%3D42601%2C+DB+Errorcode%3D500310%5D&oq=%5BSQL+State%3D42601%2C+DB+Errorcode%3D500310%5D&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDFDTmwFY05sBYKCiAWgAcAB4AIABpAGIAaQBkgEDMC4xmAEAoAECoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwioku6V_-jpAhXECOwKHUR6DOoQ4dUDCAw

Answer (score 0):

`Position: 241` indicates the error occurs at the 241st character in the SQL statement.